# Excel Row Count Formula - Error

Tags: excel, count, row

I have this Formula:

=ROW()-MATCH(LOOKUP(2,1/(D$1:INDIRECT("D" & ROW() -1)<>""),D$1:INDIRECT("D" & ROW() -1)),D$1:INDIRECT("D" & ROW() -1),0)

In order to speed up counting days between events, it simply finds the last non empty cell above it and subtracts its row value from the row value before the current cell. It was going fine for about a month and then suddenly I started getting random numbers.

[Example of random data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyWsy.jpg)

The 730 was the first error I hit so I decided to spam the formula and see what my results are and as you can see they are quite inconsistent.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated

Each cell has the proper column data input into the formula that is not the issue.

Comment: I don't know if I would subscribe to your row subtraction method but try `=row()-match(1e99, d$1:index(d:d, row()-1))` You may receive a false circular reference warning; the circular reference is within the formula but it can never be reached.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem arises from the fact that the lookup function returns the first row with the searched value.

In the example data you gave row 740, 745, and 748 are all preceded by a 1 and they all count back to row 738 (which is the first row in the column with a 1 in it).

If you want to try a cleaner formula that doesn't rely on lookups try:

> =ROW()-1-SUM(D1:INDIRECT("D" & ROW()-1))

If all previous rows are accurate (and row 1 = 0), then this should correctly count the number of days since your last event.

Answer (score 0):

Try it as,

```
=row()-match(1e99, d$1:index(d:d, row()-1))
```